# Difference between $b_{n}$ unbounded and $b_{n}$ not converging

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't understand the difference between "not convergent" and "unbounded" in the context of sequences as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Consider $\{ (-1)^n\}$. This is not convergent because the terms flip infinitely often between $1$ and $-1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, but is clearly bounded. Now consider $\{n\}$. This is unbounded since the terms go off to infinity as $n$ does.

Comment: @walkar I see, so am I correct in thinking your first example is bounded but not convergent, and your second example is both unbounded and not convergent?

Comment: Yes, usually "unbounded" is a special case of "not convergent," since convergent means a sequence approaches a real number and $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: @walkar So then $b_{n}$ is convergent $\implies b_{n}$ is bounded?

Comment: That is correct. Convergent requires bounded.

Comment: @walkar Okay thanks for your help, feel free to submit your comment as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it.

Comment: Walkar, thanks for helping her, the OP.  Maybe she gets it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider ${(-1)^n}$. This sequence is not convergent because the terms flip infinitely often between $1$ and $-1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but clearly this sequence is bounded. On the other hand, $\{n\}$ is an unbounded sequence which is also divergent, since the terms approach infinity which is not a real number.

There is a very careful way to discuss convergent sequences. A sequence $\{b_n\}$ is convergent to a real number $L$ if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n \ge m$, $|b_n-L|<\epsilon$. The first example fails because for any choice of $L$, either the distance from $1$ or the distance from $-1$ is always fixed and positive, and so cannot be made arbitrarily small (smaller than any $\epsilon >0$). The second example fails because the only choice for $L$ that works is $L=\infty$ which is not a real number.